# Deleted website from nginx but it's still accessible by URL, just with HTTPS

Tags: nginx

I have a VPS running Ubuntu + Nginx. There's an old website I'm no longer using, so I followed these steps (based on [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-safely-remove-old-url-s-server-block-wordpress-files-and-get-rid-of-301-redirect), and [these to remove the SSL](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/how-to-remove-a-domain-from-certbot-and-nginx/).

1. cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
2. sudo rm oldwebsite.com
3. cd ../sites-available
4. sudo rm oldwebsite.com

Next, I figured I could also delete the relevant files in /var/www/

5. cd /var/www/
6. sudo rm -r oldwebsite.com

Now when I try to access [www.oldwebsite.com](http://www.oldwebsite.com), I still get the same website, just without HTTPS anymore. I've checked /etc/nginx/sites-available/default for any remaining references to that website, but as far as I know, I've erased all traces of its existence from my server.

Was this the incorrect way to delete an old website?

If it helps, my old website was set up to use a reverse proxy to direct to my Express app. It was set up as a server block according to [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-5-%E2%80%93-setting-up-server-blocks-(recommended)).

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any relevant information here to help you.  You'll need to debug this further.  (And, are you sure your site is even still accessible... not just cached somewhere?)  Is your hostname pointed to this server?  If you use cURL, can you see that this server is actually serving it?  Are you even using Nginx, and not some other server?  So many possibilities.

Comment: @Brad thank you, sorry it’s my bad, I checked again just now and the website is now showing the default apache page instead of my website. With everything else basically updating instantly, I wasn’t expecting this to take so long. Would you say this is the correct way to remove an old website in an nginx server? I couldn’t find a definitive guide for this.

Comment: Your title and the steps you describe relate to nginx, not Apache - they are both web servers, but unless you have a more complex set up, you are running only one of them, not both.  If you are now seeing an Apache default page ... there is something more going on that you haven't described.  One other note - nginx needs to be restarted before any config changes take effect.  Maybe you rebooted the server or something, which would cause nginx to restart, which might explain the delay?

Comment: My apologies again, I did mean the nginx default page not apache. Than you so much for the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all if you dont want to make it accessable anymore delete the Host A record on your DNS. With this the DNS query will not point to any severs IP address.

Based on your comment: If its showing the APACHE defaults page your DNS points to an IP address of an webserver running httpd. So let me draft a couple of steps for you how I would do it (as somebody how moved 10K of sites from and to NGINX).

### 1. DNS is key

Check the current DNS Setting for your domain. Do a quick lookup using tools like `host` or `dig`.

```
$# host nginx.org
nginx.org has address 52.58.199.22
```

So great now we know the public IPv4 of our WebServer (we are not talking about LoadBalancers or anything else in between. We asume the webserver is directly conncted to the internet.)

### 2. WebServer configuration

On your server make sure nginx is installed and listening on port 80 for example.

```
$# netstat -tulpn | grep "LISTEN"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25674/nginx: master
```

Great. We have NGINX listen on Port 80. Let make sure we can send reuqest.

```
$# curl -v http://YOURDOMAIN
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.19.5
< Date: Sun, 14 Feb 2021 08:47:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 10
< Connection: keep-alive
<
localhost
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

So if you got an response that means your NGINX is up and running, listening on port 80 and there is no firewall (ufw, firewalld, iptables, security-groups...) blocking your from reaching out to the server.

#### NOTICE: Make sure your firewall setup is done right. Let me know if you need more information on that depending on your systems architecture.

### NGINX Configuration

Lets say your website should just print out a String saying "We will be here shortly!"

Based on your OS the configuration directory for custom nginx files can be different. Check the default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file and see the `include` path in the `http` context. This should be something like: `include conf.d/*.conf` or `sites-enabled/*.conf`. Create a conf-file in one of that directories.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name YOURDOMAIN.com
  
  location {
    add_hedaer "Content-Type: text/html";
    return 200 "We will be here shortly!\n";
  }
}
```

With this simple setup you can have a webserver up and running but not showing anyhing special. If you want to create a little html file feel free to do so and use `root` and `index` to configure it in your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting enter command `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: This not the complete answer!

Comment: Still the same.